# Class Bundle not found in symfony

Tags: php, symfony-3.4

I have created the following bundle.

```
{
  "name": "team/test-service-bundle",
  "description": "bundle to work with the test service",
  "type": "symfony-bundle",
  "license" : [
    "proprietary"
  ],
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "Print\\TestServiceBundle\\": "src/" 
    },
    "classmap": [
      "app/AppKernel.php",
      "app/AppCache.php"
    ]
  },
}
```

Now I want to use this in another symfony project. So I run the below command in my symfony project.

> sudo ln -s /opt/lampp/htdocs/testabc/test-service-bundle
>   vendor/team/test-service-bundle

AppKernal.php in Symfony project,

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface;

class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = [
           ...
            new \Print\TestServiceBundle\PrintTestServiceBundle(),
        ];
    }
}
```

I am getting following error,

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught
>   Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to
>   load class "PrintTestServiceBundle" from namespace
>   "Print\TestServiceBundle".

Comment: I think you have an extra  `psr-4`. Not sure but I used to define my namespaces with `"autoload": {"psr-4": {"App\\": "src/"}},`

Comment: It was my typo. But still doesn't work

Comment: What if you copy the files instead of creating a symbolic link ?